# futures.wait does not timeout in concurrent.futures in python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency

I have the following code

```
def multiprocess(dbs, tables, timeout=None):
    """
    Run all the processes for each table at the same time
    :param dbs: list of database objects
    :param tables: list: tables to work on
    :param timeout: timeout time
    :return: list of results
    """
    # Sort the source
    results = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as thread:
        jobs = {thread.submit(procedure, db, table) for db in dbs for table in tables}
        done, running = futures.wait(jobs, timeout=1, return_when=futures.ALL_COMPLETED)

    for job in jobs:
        if job.done():
            results.append(job.result())

    return results
```

The problem is that the timeout never occurs. It only returns when all are completed. What should I be doing?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code and it now seems to do what I want. I now understand it does not leave the context until everything is finished

```
def multiprocess(dbs, tables, timeout=0):
    """
    Run all the processes for each table at the same time
    :param dbs: list of database objects
    :param tables: list: tables to work on
    :param timeout: timeout time
    :return: list of results
    """
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as thread:
        jobs = {thread.submit(procedure, db, table) for db in dbs for table in tables}
        done, not_done = futures.wait(jobs, timeout=timeout)
        print(f"Done {done}")
        for job in done:
            yield job.result()

    print(f"Not Done {not_done}")
    for job in not_done:
        yield job.result()
```